# XQuery replace multiple words from a node

Tags: xquery, basex

Following is the XML File -

```
<A>
  <B>
    <Data>John is a good</Data>
    <Data>James loves cricket</Data>
    <Data>John loves Hockey</Data>
  </B>
  <B>
    <Data>Stuart loves cricket</Data>
    <Data>Johny loves Hockey</Data>
  </B>
</A>
```

I want to replace all the words except the names (James, John, Stuart) from the node `Data`. I am trying to do this job in a single go.

Following is the XQuery -

```
for $words in ("Hockey", "crikcet", "is")
let $word := $words
   for $x in doc('file')//Data
      where contains($x, $word)
      return replace value of node $x with normalize-space(replace($x, $word, ''))
```

I am getting Error-
`[XUDY0017] Node can only be replaced once: element Data ...`

I am using BaseX 7.6

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, you should update to an up-to-date version of BaseX. It currently is at version 8.2.x and 7.6. is out of support since a long time.

Secondly, your whole approach does not feel particularly XQuery-like. For example, instead of doing

```
for $words in ("Hockey", "crikcet", "is")
let $word := $words
```

the following line does exactly the same but is shorter and easier

```
for $word in ("Hockey", "crikcet", "is")
```

Because of the two for-loops, the same node could be used twice or more often here, if one data value contains multiple hits. This is when your error message comes up (which actually does not happen in your provided sample data set, because each data value contains exactly one search string).

Replacing each value multiple times does not work, because XQuery Update applies updates according to the Pending Update List (PUL), i.e. at the end of the query. If you want to replace the same data value twice, the processor of course does not really know what to replace it with. Instead, you should compute the replace value by yourself and then replace the complete value. And this is were recursion comes in, with your use case being a fantastic example. Hence, the following should work:

```
declare function local:replace-word($word as xs:string, $search as xs:string*, $replace as xs:string*) as xs:string {
  if (empty($search)) then $word
  else replace(local:replace-word($word, tail($search), tail($replace)), head($search), head($replace))
};

let $words := ("Hockey", "cricket", "is")
let $replace := ("Replace1", "Replace2", "Replace3")
  for $x in //Data
  return replace value of node $x with normalize-space(local:replace-word($x, $words, $replace))
```

So, what does it do? First of, I introduced a second sequence with values you want to replace with. In your query, you always replace with an empty string, i.e. you delete the word, which is not what your question is asking for. Also, I replace your typo in `cricket`.

We now only have one for loop in it iterates over each `Data` element. The it calls the `local:replace-word` function. This functions calls itself (hence: recursion) until no search/replace words are in the sequence anymore. `head()` gets the first item in a sequence, whereas `last()` gets all the other values in the sequence.

Comment: Thanks. Very good explanation. Downloaded the latest version of BaseX.

Answer (score 1):

Just make sure that every node is only touched once by exchanging the two loops. Here is one possibility with some [lambda magic](http://docs.basex.org/wiki/XQuery_3.0#Function_Items) to make all replacements one after the other:

```
let $words := ("Hockey", "cricket", "is")
for $data in doc('file')//Data
where some $word in $words satisfies contains($data, $word)
return
  replace value of node $data
  with normalize-space(fold-left($words, $data, replace(?, ?, '')))
```

Comment: Thanks. Now in difficult situation whose answer to accepted. :)